# Font awesome selector color

Tags: css, font-awesome

I was wondering if it was possible to change the **selector** color of the font awesome icon

I know its possible to change it of everything except the font awesome by using this code

```
::selection{
    background: #ffb7b7 !important; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

[image: example]

I also tested the following:

```
.icon-2x::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7 !important; 
    }
i::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7 !important; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the font-awesome CSS injects the icon using a `::before` pseudo-element, and browsers seem to fail to properly select that. Note that if there is a line-break before the icon and you select the previous line too, it works (sort of).

A workaround is to add the character directly on your markup (in this case, it's `&#61459;`). **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YJP2n/)**.

If course this will only work on elements with `font-family: FontAwesome` (the font awesome CSS adds that to all elements with class `icon-[something]`).

Comment: +1 This makes my work around look like crap because mine is much longer, haha

Comment: @Zeaklous Turns out you were right from the beginning: it's just a font.

Answer (score 1):

***It's a font***, so you simply use `color`

```
i::selection {
    background: #ffb7b7; 
    color:red;
}
```

**EDIT**

[Here is the closes you can get without adding any HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/yUYnx/1/). You can't select font awesome icons, just the stuff inside

**EDIT 2**

If you're willing to use a tiny bit of javascript you can do it using a surrounding div [**like this version**](http://jsfiddle.net/yUYnx/3/). You can make it exactly the way you want by customizing the colros. Let me know if you have any other questions.

The code

```
<div class='selectable'><i id='newSelect0' class="icon-cog"></i>.</div>

// CSS
i {
    background: transparent;
    color:black;
}
.selectable {
    color:transparent;
}
.selectable::selection {
    color:transparent;
}

// Javascript
setInterval(function () {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    var selectable = document.getElementsByClassName('selectable');
    for(var t = 0; t < selectable.length; t++)
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById('newSelect' + t);
        if (text != '' && window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode == selectable[t]) {
            elem.style.background = '#ffb7b7';
            elem.style.color = 'green';
        } else {
            elem.style.background = 'white';
            elem.style.color = 'black';
        }
    }
}, 20);
```

Comment: Then you're only changing the font color not the selector color 
also its not even changing the icon color

Comment: I'm trying to change the selector color not the color of the font

Comment: I'm trying to change the selector color not the font color